# MySQL Query: Calculate Biggest Daily/Weekly Price Increases/Decreases

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have the following 3 tables:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `item` (
 `id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
 `subcategory` mediumint(9) NOT NULL,
 `name` varchar(64) NOT NULL,
 `pagetitle` varchar(128) NOT NULL,
 `metadescription` varchar(256) NOT NULL,
 `properties` varchar(256) NOT NULL,
 `specification` text NOT NULL,
 `summary` text NOT NULL,
 `homepage` varchar(256) NOT NULL default 'none',
 PRIMARY KEY  (`id`)
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `link` (
  `id` mediumint(9) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `item` mediumint(9) NOT NULL,
  `merchant` mediumint(9) NOT NULL,
  `rawlink` varchar(256) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`)
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `prices` (
  `id` mediumint(9) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `link` mediumint(9) NOT NULL,
  `timestamp` date NOT NULL,
  `price` float NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`)
);
```

These tables hold data for a price comparison website.

Each item has several links (to the different shops) **link.item = item.id**.

Each link has several prices (one for each day of tracking) **prices.link = link.id**.

**PROBLEM**

I want to create an MySQL query which returns:

1. The top 3 daily price increases across all items
2. The top 3 daily price decreases across all items

So far I have come up with this:

```
SELECT item.name AS iname, item.id AS iid,
((SELECT MIN(price) FROM prices, link WHERE prices.timestamp = CURDATE() AND link.id = prices.link AND link.item = iid) - 
(SELECT MIN(price) FROM prices, link WHERE prices.timestamp = CURDATE() - INTERVAL 1 DAY AND link.id = prices.link AND link.item = iid))
AS changeprice
FROM prices, link, item
WHERE link.id = prices.link AND link.item = item.id
GROUP BY link.item
ORDER BY changeprice DESC
LIMIT 0,3
```

It technically works, but is an inefficient solution (the server times out).

I know it works as I have limited the items to increase the speed by adding this extra WHERE clause:

```
item.id BETWEEN '20' AND '30'
```

I currently have 55 items, and this is proving too many, so I need a faster/simpler solution.

I've found [this alternative solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1250675/how-can-i-calculate-the-top-daily-price-changes-using-mysql), however it doesn't seem to work (I get an error).

Thanks in advance!

**SAMPLE DATA**

```
INSERT INTO `item` (`id`, `subcategory`, `name`, `pagetitle`, `metadescription`, `properties`, `specification`, `summary`, `homepage`) VALUES
(1, 5, 'Item 1', 'TEST', 'TEST', '0', 'TEST', 'TEST', 'TEST'),
(2, 5, 'Item 2', 'TEST', 'TEST', '0', 'TEST', 'TEST', 'TEST'),
(3, 5, 'Item 3', 'TEST', 'TEST', '0', 'TEST', 'TEST', 'TEST');

INSERT INTO `link` (`id`, `item`, `merchant`, `rawlink`) VALUES
(1, 1, 1, 'TEST'),
(2, 1, 2, 'TEST'),
(3, 1, 3, 'TEST'),
(4, 2, 1, 'TEST'),
(5, 2, 2, 'TEST'),
(6, 2, 3, 'TEST'),
(7, 3, 1, 'TEST'),
(8, 3, 2, 'TEST'),
(9, 3, 3, 'TEST');

INSERT INTO `prices` (`id`, `link`, `timestamp`, `price`) VALUES
(1, 1, '2013-02-07', 110.00),
(2, 1, '2013-02-06', 75.00),
(3, 2, '2013-02-07', 105.00),
(4, 2, '2013-02-06', 100.00),
(5, 3, '2013-02-07', 105.00),
(6, 3, '2013-02-06', 100.00),
(7, 4, '2013-02-07', 50.00),
(8, 4, '2013-02-06', 50.00),
(9, 5, '2013-02-07', 50.00),
(10, 5, '2013-02-06', 50.00),
(11, 6, '2013-02-07', 50.00),
(12, 6, '2013-02-06', 50.00),
(13, 7, '2013-02-07', 10.00),
(14, 7, '2013-02-06', 4.00),
(15, 8, '2013-02-07', 8.00),
(16, 8, '2013-02-06', 6.00),
(17, 9, '2013-02-07', 10.00),
(18, 9, '2013-02-06', 10.00);
```

**EXPECTED OUTPUT**

```
Item 1 - 30
Item 3 - 4
Item 2 - 0
```

To clarify: Item 1 = 30 because:

(Item 1 lowest price today) - (Item 1 lowest price yesterday)

= (link 2 & 3 are 105.00 today) - (link 1 was 75.00 yesterday)

= (105.00) - (75.00) = 30

(link 1, link 2 and link 3 all belong to item 1. I need the min price today (out of these 3 links) - what the min price was yesterday (out of these 3 links)).

**WEBSITE EXAMPLE**

I compare prices for the iPad. (item1 = iPad).

I link to 3 shops which sell the iPad. (link1 = Amazon, link2 = eBay, link3 = Argos).

Each link has a price history. (Amazon is 110.00 today, but was 75.00 yesterday. eBay is 105.00 today, but was 100.00 yesterday. Argos is 105.00 today, but was 100.00 yesterday.)

Therefore, the minimum prices are as follows:

Today = eBay and Arogs (105.00)
Yesterday = Amazon (75.00)

The price increase for the iPad is 30.00.

Comment: Why not give us some data (and a desired result) to play with

Comment: I've added some sample data. Let me know if you need anything else. Thanks.

Comment: Why didn't you update your DDLs as per @echo_Me's advice?

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
  select item.name AS iname, item.id AS iid ,changeprice from(
  select t1.link, min(pricem) - min(pricemm) as changeprice from (
  select id , link, price pricemm from prices
  where prices.timestamp = CURDATE() - INTERVAL 1 DAY
  group by price)t1
  inner join(
  select id , link, price pricem from prices
  where prices.timestamp = CURDATE() 
  group by price )t2
  on t1.link = t2.link
  )t3
  INNER JOIN link
  ON t3.link = link.id
  inner join item 
  ON link.item = item.id

  group by link.item
  ORDER BY changeprice DESC
  LIMIT 3 ;
```

EDIT:

your Create form are wrong , dont use single quotes around columns and tables name , intead use backtickes -> ' ` '

or use those:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `item` (
 id int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
 subcategory mediumint(9) NOT NULL,
 name varchar(64) NOT NULL,
 pagetitle varchar(128) NOT NULL,
 metadescription varchar(256) NOT NULL,
 properties varchar(256) NOT NULL,
 specification text NOT NULL,
 summary text NOT NULL,
 homepage varchar(256) NOT NULL default 'none',
 PRIMARY KEY  (id)
 );
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS link (
id mediumint(9) NOT NULL auto_increment,
item mediumint(9) NOT NULL,
merchant mediumint(9) NOT NULL,
rawlink varchar(256) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY  (id)
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS prices (
 id mediumint(9) NOT NULL auto_increment,
 link mediumint(9) NOT NULL,
 timestamp date NOT NULL,
 price float NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY  (id)
 );
```

**EDIT:**

there was 3 entries and the first one is not 0 its -36,04

try replace this last group by

```
   group by link.item
```

by

```
   group by t3.link
```

[**DEMO here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9bd88/11)
note that there is 3 different prices.link.

**EDIT2**
its little long query but it gives what you want.

```
 select iname , iid , min(changeprice) changeprice from (
 select t1.iname , t1.iid , pricem - pricemm as changeprice from 
 (select item.name AS iname, item.id AS iid ,min(price) pricem from prices
  INNER JOIN link
  ON prices.link = link.id
  inner join item 
  ON link.item = item.id
  where prices.timestamp = CURDATE()
  group by item.name
  ORDER BY price DESC
   )t1,
  ( select item.name AS iname, item.id AS iid ,min(price) pricemm from prices
  INNER JOIN link
  ON prices.link = link.id
  inner join item 
  ON link.item = item.id
  where prices.timestamp = CURDATE() - INTERVAL 1 DAY
  group by item.name
  ORDER BY price DESC
  )t2
  having changeprice >=0
  ORDER BY changeprice DESC
  )h
  group by iname
  order by changeprice desc  LIMIT 3
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2dfe7/12

Comment: Thanks echo_Me - it almost works (certainly faster!) - but I found the values are incorrect (see my edits to your answer).

Comment: what was wrong ? i dont see any update, write what you updated alone.

Comment: No - this still doesn't work correctly. I need a single 'changeprice' for each item (not each link).

Comment: Sorry.. no. It now doesn't work with original test data.

Comment: Ok - I corrected dates, and results are 35 - 6 - 0 (should be 30 - 4 - 0) - [DEMO HERE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a2ff3/2/0)

Comment: ^^This demo is with your original code (which is closer than your edited code). Thanks.

Comment: Please see my edit. link1, link2 and link3 all belong to item1. I need (min price today for item1) - (min price yesterday for item1). Thanks for your help.

Comment: Sorry - still not working with bigger data sample size: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2dfe7/9

Comment: No - should be (Item1: 30 > Item3: 4 > Item2: 0) Why -71 ? 0 should come first.... Really appreciate your help (y)

Comment: take a look here maybe its right , just verify if data gives right result http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2dfe7/12

Comment: Still incorrect - Item 3 changeprice = 4 (4.00 was best price yesterday, 8.00 is best price today).

Comment: i think Item 3 changeprice = 5 because link 7 is not for item3 so i think my query is right

Comment: No. Link7, Link8, Link9 are matched to Item3. (Look at their link.item value - row47 - row49 on your demo). http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2dfe7/12

Comment: You can use my original solution to confirm the correct values.